# Rails elsif syntax to assign value to new variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

Building a Ruby on Rails app that requires users select a 1-3 price levels and enter a price for each level selected. The higher levels will always have a higher price associated with them. `level_avail` options are 1, 2, 3 and corresponding price variables are `price`, `price2`, and `price3`

I am trying to write an `if` statement to first check the `levels_avail` option selected by the user and set a new variable to the corresponding price. The code below seems to work fine but when I call `@max_saving` in my view nothing is returned. Any help is appreciated.

#### Model Code

```rb
def max_saving (levels_avail)
  if levels_avail == 1
    @max_saving = price
  elsif
    levels_avail == 2
    @max_saving = price2
  else
    @max_saving = price3
  end
end
```

#### View Code

```erb
<div id="offer-title"> Up To <%= @max_saving %> Off! </div>
```

Comment: Have you actuall called `max_saving`? what framework is this? does the view see the model instance variables?

Comment: Ruby on Rails frame work. I called max saving in the view via <%= @max_saving %> line. the view does see the model variables.

Comment: Having a condition on a different line than `elsif` is so bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

`<%= @max_saving %>` doesn't call the `max_saving` function, it just reads the `@max_saving` variable that is set by the `max_saving` function. You need to actually call `max_saving` somewhere in your controller, under the action that is run. Like this:

```rb
def index # or whatever action
  # a bunch of existing code
  levels_available = 2 # get this data from wherever it comes from
  max_saving(levels_available)
  # more existing code
end
```

Or you could change `max_saving` to a custom helper that takes only parameters and doesn't read instance variables.